# Eclipse could not find artifact on local maven-plugin module

Tags: eclipse, maven

I have a maven project with 1 parent and 5 modules. One of the modules (call it P) is of packaging "maven-plugin", which is configured to be run in the execution phase "process-test-classes of other module (call it T).

The module T has pom.xml as follows. I omitted dependencies, but they don't include P. As in many other cases it all works perfectly in command line.

**Question**: Whatever I do Eclipse shows *"Could not find artifact org.local.enhancer:pom:0.0.2-SNAPSHOT   pom.xml /test   line 1  Maven Configuration Problem*".

Seems like the issue started after installing "m2e-wtp" v0.17 to resolve other issue with offending jars. Configuration is Eclipse Juno SR2, m2e v1.3.1,  m2e-wtp v0.17.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
          <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
          <parent>
            <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.local</groupId>
            <version>0.0.2</version>
            <relativePath>..</relativePath>
          </parent>
          <artifactId>test</artifactId>
            <dependencies>
                 ...
            </dependencies>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.local</groupId>
                        <artifactId>enhancer</artifactId>
                        <version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version> 
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>process-test-classes</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>enhance</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>    
        </project>
```

Does anybody have any insight on this? Thanks!

Comment: Uninstalled m2e-wtp from Eclipse, problem goes away. Completely puzzling.

Comment: This means your are using a maven plugin which is build during the build you need it. Sounds completely wrong. Make a separate project of the maven plugin write unit and integration tests for the plugin and release it separateley cause you are combining the build tools and your application.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, installing it separately resolved the issue. All I had to do is remove <parent> tag from the maven-plugin module and install it separately, IDE does not show that error anymore with m2e-wtp installed. For convenience I still keep maven-plugin as a module of the parent as in [Maven aggregation without inheritance](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Aggregation). khmarbaise please write the answer below I will accept it.